# taskwarrior, delete multiple recurring tasks without request for deleting all pending

Tags: taskwarrior

Returning from holidays, I want to delete all recurrent daily routines not done during absence. For this i use:

```
task 100-200 delete
```

Then I confirm the request:

```
Delete task 100 'Drink: water, 0.7l, before 10:00'? (yes/no/all/quit)
```

with `a` (for all)

And then I have to answer for **each task** (here 101x):

```
Do you want to delete all pending recurrences of this same task
```

with `n` (for no). This part is annoying and I want to get rid of this step. I consider if someone would want to apply `delete` to *all* tasks with `a`, it should be at least be possible to avoid answering if he wants to delete recurrences with `n` or `never` (for none).

Do you know some way how to avoid this mess? Or do I'm -- as sometimes -- missing something?

PS: It should be noticed that, if you confirm the discussed 2nd request with `y` (for yes), the **parent/template task is deleted too!** What makes this request even dangerous, since in a hurry you might delete a whole recurrent task by accident -- e.g. `pay rent`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding

```
recurrence.confirmation=no
```

to your `.taskrc` should do what you want.

More information from `man taskrc`:

```
recurrence.confirmation=prompt
    Controls whether changes to recurring tasks propagates to other child tasks with or with‐
    out confirmation. A value of 'yes' means propagate changes without confirmation. A  value
    of  'no'  means  do  not  propagate  changes  and  don't ask for confirmation. A value of
    'prompt' prompts you every time. Defaults to 'prompt'.
```